Permissions for this object are disabled
To enable my setup to create custom objects, I need to understand how to activate the required permissions. It seems that the current configuration of my setup is preventing me from creating custom objects, and I am not sure how to resolve this issue.
I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to modify my setup so that I can enable the creation of custom objects. Specifically, I need to know which settings or permissions need to be adjusted, and the steps required to make these changes. Detailed instructions or resources that outline the process of enabling these permissions would be incredibly helpful.
In summary, I am seeking assistance to enable the creation of custom objects within my current setup. The main issue I am encountering is that the permissions required for creating custom objects are disabled. I need to know how to enable these permissions and any additional steps that may be necessary to ensure that I can create custom objects without any further issues.
Your assistance in this matter would be invaluable, as it would allow me to proceed with creating the custom objects I need. Thank you in advance for your support and guidance.
im standing by for your assistance
